# Receiving Error: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find a record in the table "Order Status" with key matching field(s) "Status ID"

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am trying to use MySQL as the backend for Northwind 2007 Sample. In one of the forms I am getting the above error. I have moved all tables to MySQL, matched the data types, created the foreign keys. The data is being displayed and corrected in the database. However I get this error the error in a subform.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in table and field names. If you insist, wrap them in brackets in Access:

```
[Order Status]
[Status ID]
```

In MySQL, use quotes.

Comment: I am using brackets:                      SELECT Orders.[Order ID], Orders.[Employee ID], Orders.[Customer ID], Orders.[Order Date], Orders.[Shipped Date], [Order Price Totals].[Price Total] AS [Sub Total], Orders.[Shipping Fee], Orders.Taxes, [Sub Total]+[Shipping Fee]+[Taxes] AS [Order Total], Orders.[Ship Name], Orders.[Ship Address], Orders.[Paid Date], [Orders Status].[Status Name]
FROM [Orders Status] RIGHT JOIN (Orders LEFT JOIN [Order Price Totals] ON Orders.[Order ID] = [Order Price Totals].OrderID) ON [Orders Status].[Status ID] = Orders.[Status ID]
ORDER BY Orders.[Order ID] DESC;

Comment: Then you probably pass no or a wrong value to [Status ID] in your subform.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out, infact it was just a lucky guess. Changed the join type.

Comment: Yes, they must match.